# Why does this program run only once?

Tags: c, recursion

So I'm trying to be able to raise a number to a certain power through a recursive function. My code seems correct to me but it behaves strangely in that it only runs once. I can't seem to understand why.

```
double to_pow(int zahl, int potenz){
    zahl+=zahl;
    potenz-=1;
    if(potenz!=0){
        to_pow(zahl, potenz);
    }
    return zahl;
}

int main(){

    double res = to_pow(9,3);
    printf("%.lf", res);
}
```

Comment: You're ignoring the return value of `to_pow`. And it looks like you're implementing multiplication, not exponentiation.

Comment: @tkausi Thought that at first, too, but it is something completely different... I think it is `zahl * 2^potenz`

Comment: `return to_pow(zahl, potenz);`

Comment: @goodvibration I get an error. Segmentation fault: 11.

Comment: @Ariel.H This can only happen on an endless recursion, for example when `potenz <= 0`

Comment: What does "run only once" mean anyway? You start it, then it produces some (incorrect) output, then it ends. You start it again, it runs again.

Comment: BTW, you don't seem to need `double` here at all. And `int` looks bad in general. Use `unsigned int`, or better yet - `unsigned long long` conclusively. In addition to all of that, your stop condition should be **opposite** to what you wrote AND appear **at the beginning of the function**: `if (potenz == 0) return 1;`.

Comment: Conclusion: In order to find out what's wrong with your code, you should first learn how recursive algorithms are implemented. Then it should be obvious.

Comment: @goodvibration If I put the condition in the beginning, it gives me a warning  ```control may reach end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
```

Comment: @Ctx E.g. it returns 18 instead of 27. It only runs once.

Comment: @Ariel.H the code you posted here works fine. And it looks correct to me. What output do _you_ expect? The output I get here is `18`, but I'm not sure what this code is supposed to do.

Comment: @Jabberwocky It's supposed to give me 27, by adding the input 9 + 9 + 9, instead it only runs once.

Comment: The question has been closed, so I cannot add a prope answer: Actually the name of the function is misleading, it should be `double multiply(int double number, double multiplier)`, (you commented that the result of `to_pow(9, 3)` should be 27 (that's 9 x 3). And the code should be this: `double multiply(int number, int multiplier) {
  if (multiplier == 0)
    return 0;
  else
   return number + multiply(number, multiplier - 1);
}`.

Comment: @Jabberwocky It's now reopened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me try to address this question:

> *Why does my recursive algorithm appear to run only once?*

The recursion is actually done, but it has no effect on the output value. The recursively computed results are ignored.

Here's some annotations that might make this clearer:

```
double to_pow(int zahl, int potenz){
    // we double the first input value and decrease the second input value
    zahl+=zahl;
    potenz-=1;
    if(potenz!=0){
        // depending on some criterion we call the function recursively
        // but the function has no side-effects and the return value is not used
        to_pow(zahl, potenz);
    }
    // we return the doubled input value
    return zahl;
}
```

To fix this, you should use the return value of the recursive function call, to actually calculate the final output of the algorithm.

Once you have this, you should address the other issues with the implementation, i.e. that it actually does what it's supposed to do.

Answer (score 2):

1. You don't seem to need `double` here to begin with, since your input is integer and your function does not support the computation of negative powers (which would yield non-integer results); so the return-value type should be integer
2. For the same reason, the exponent type should be non-negative integer
3. Your logic is wrong in several places (including, as others have explained in the comments to your question, the fact that you do not return the recursive function-call)

Instead of explaining every bit of wrongity, may I suggest that you simply try this one:

```
long long to_pow(long long zahl, unsigned int potenz) {
    if (potenz == 0)
        return 1;
    return zahl * to_pow(zahl, potenz - 1);
}

int main() {
    long long res = to_pow(9, 3);
    printf("%lld", res);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: **You don't seem to need double**...it really depends on the range of values you want to cover...

Comment: @LPs: 1. `long long` should do the job. And I believe that not every value above `2 ^ 64 - 1` will necessarily be accurate if we pass `double zahl` and return a `double` value. Hence we should stick with integers. My belief stems from the fact that `sizeof(long long) == sizeof(double)`, hence it is not possible for `double` to represent accurately every possible integer value which doesn't fit into `long long`.

Comment: `sizeof(long long) == sizeof(double)` not true on all platform. `c99`says that 
 `long long` is **at least** 64 bits. You should always refer to `stdint.h` type. So `int64_t` in this case. Moreover range og **signed** `long long` is from -`2 ^ 63 ` to `2 ^ 63 - 1 `

Answer (score 1):

use this instead:

```
double to_pow(int zahl, int potenz){
    potenz--;
    if(potenz!=0){
        zahl = zahl * to_pow(zahl, potenz);
    }
    return zahl;
}

int main(){
    double res = to_pow(9,3);
    printf("%.lf\n", res);
}
```

This is the reason:
9^3 = 9 * 9^2 = 9 * (9 * 9^1) = 9 * (9 * (9 * 9^0))